# Android :How to call Cordova(WebView) loadUrl function

Tags: javascript, android, json, cordova, webview

Well i am into a VOIP application development.Below is my architecture.

UI: Uses Cordova with JS functions.

Sencha Touch : HTML5 Framework.

Backend: uses C code(engine).

JNI: Use JNI to call C function and Vice Versa.

Platform: Android.

Now we have a single activity which extends the Cordova.

Cordova:

1)Has an activity which loads a webview.

2)All we call is [loadUrl](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl%28java.lang.String%29) with JS functions

3)JS functions will take [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) as data,or just a UI display JS function.

**Right now we call loadUrl in AsyncTask and by creating Handler in broadcastreceiver ,and on [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) of activity.
We see some lag in UI transitions and ANR's.  **

Data is received from non UI thread,Now how do i call loadUrl function?

1) Doc says(Loads the given URL), which means it should be called on UI main thread only?

2) Can i create a Handler in plain java class and call loadUrl in handleMessage function?

3)Create a handler in main activity and call loadUrl in handleMessage?

4)runOnUiThread is best way?

5)If the loadUrl should be called on UI main thread how do achieve the same?

6)What is best way to call loadUrl?

Comment: Right now we call loadUrl in AsyncTask and by creating Handler in broadcastreceiver !!! why this?? explain your issue properly

Answer (score 1):

You're doing that in the right way. Try to get the data in the async mode and then assign it in the main thread by using. This might help http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html .